# Deriving the essential matrix using the scalar triple product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, computer-vision

I'm trying to test my understanding by deriving famous results from computer vision.  This one: the essential matrix.

I'm using the scalar triple product to encode the co-planarity constraint.

I'm assuming the camera center of projection that corresponds to $x_0$ is the origin, and the rotation for the first camera is the identity matrix.  I'm assuming the rotation and translation of the second camera with respect to the first is $R$ and $T$ respectively.

The strategy is to derive three vectors from this setup, and then use the scalar triple product to get the essential matrix.

Here's my math:

$$A \cdot (B \times C) = 0$$
$$A = R^{-1}x_1 = R^{T}x_1$$
$$B = T$$
$$C = x_0$$
$$A = R^{T}x_1 \cdot [T]_{x}x_{0}$$
$$A = x_1^{T}R[T]_{x}x_{0}$$
$$A = x_1^{T}Ex_{0}$$
$$E = R[T]_{x} $$

The correct answer is $E = [T]_{x}R$.  If I had to guess, I think I may have account for the translation in the $A$ vector somehow.  But I'm not sure, since it's a direction only -- it should still encode the co-planarity constraint?  Please advise.